# PHP - Array Unique and count elements

Tags: php, arrays

I am developing a shopping cart and come across a problem with regards to unique purchases.

Let's say that there is a product "Product A" and the user buys this item 4 times, their shopping cart shows as "4" items in the basket, which is stored as:

```
$items = [
  "Product A" => array (),
  "Product A" => array(),
  "Product B" => array()
];
```

When they view the shopping cart, I want it to therefore show:

```
Product:          Quantity:

"Product A"          2
"Product B"          1
```

Therefore, the question is, whether or not it is possible to do a `array_unique` with a count? So, I could store all of the unique items but also get the number of items that they have ordered? Or is there an alternative approach to this problem?

Comment: Your initial array structure is impossible, you cannot have the same key twice... How about you store the product *and a quantity counter* with it?

Comment: `$items = ["Product A" => array(), "Product A" => array()"]` is invalid. Same key can only appear once in an array.

Comment: use `in_array()` before adding product to cart

Comment: i think you should change in your query ? and try to improve it . so you will get this kind of data directly using your query

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the structure of your array:

```
$items = [];

function addItem($name, array $data = []){
    global $items;
    $items[$name][] = $data;
}

function countItem($name){
    global $items;
    return count($items[$name]);
}
```

So `$items` will end up like this:

```
$items = [
    "Product A" => [
        array(),
        array(),
    ],
    "Product B" => [
        array()
    ]
];
```

`$array[] = $element` will create an empty array `$array` if it is undefined. Similarly, `$array["a"][] = $element` will create an empty array `$array["a"]` if it is not defined yet.

Or if you only want to store a count, you have to use `if(!isset($array["a"])) $array["a"] = 0;` before incrementing it with `$array["a"]++`.

Answer (score 0):

**Following is the logic.**

1) Create a blank array of product cart.

2) While adding item to array, check `array_key_exists()`.

3) If does not exist, add item to array as key and quantity as value (this is quantity).

4) If exists, increase quantity by one.

Thats it.

Comment: Not `in_array`, instead `isset` or `array_key_exists`...!

Comment: @pupil - Thanks for this. But how would I be able to get the total amount of products in the shopping basket?